# Change log format of Cloudwatch logs from Lambda (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

If I do `console.log('message')` in my code, it shows up in Cloudwatch as
`2017-03-16T18:58:21.823Z   863c835c-0a7a-11e7-9140-e5018d6e5029 message`.

Is there any way to remove the automatic formatting so that Cloudwatch just displays the argument I pass to `console.log`?

Comment: What "automatic formatting are you referring to? Each Lambda log message is prepended with a timestamp and the Lambda invocation ID. Without that information the logs would be a total mess.

Comment: that is the automatic formatting. the request id could easily be reduced to fewer characters, separators could be added between time, request id, and message to make it easier to parse...do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The weirdest thing is that node.js is the only runtime that shows this behaviour, if you print something to stdout in your lambda running python or java it does not add the automatic formatting

Answer (score 8):

Inside your handler you can overwrite `console.log` to write directly to `stdout`:

```
var util = require('util')

module.exports.handler = function (event, context, done) {
  console.log = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    process.stdout.write(args.map(function (arg) {
      return util.isPrimitive(arg) ? String(arg) : util.inspect(arg)
    }).join(' '))
  }

  // the rest of your handler...
}
```

Comment: great, this is what i was looking for. it seems like this is happening asynchronously though. having trouble finding a "flush" solution. do you know of a way to make this synchronous?

Comment: @maniciam unfortunately no. A non-perfect solution would be to replace your handler's `done` callback function with something like `const finish = (err, data) => process.stdout.write('done', () => done(err, data))` and then call `finish()` instead of calling `done()` directly.

Comment: You can set the stdout handle to blocking for Lambda.
process.stdout._handle.setBlocking(true);

Answer (score 4):

This code helped me to get rid of '<awsRequestId> <logLevel>' when we do console.log

```js
const { Console } = require('console');
console.log = new Console({ stdout: process.stdout, stderr: process.stderr }).log;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is a link to the nodejs Console class: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#class-console

Comment: Also, you might want to replace all of the following functions on the console object: `log`, `info`, `warn`, `error`, `debug`.