# Remove metadata from AWS Lambda logs

Tags: node.js, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, datadog

I have a serverless application with many Lambdas. I'm using the [Datadog Lambda Extension](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/libraries_integrations/extension/) to push logs to Datadog.

My Lambda logs are very cluttered since they have the timestamp, requestID, and log level associated with each log (along with the Datadog trace id). Is there a way to remove this metadata from logs, and just have the content that is logged (and ideally preserve the log level too?). For reference, we are using the standard `console.log`, `console.warn`, etc... methods.

Comment: The metadata is there for a reason. https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/manage-serverless-logs-datadog/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change log format of Cloudwatch logs from Lambda (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843905/change-log-format-of-cloudwatch-logs-from-lambda-node-js)